# Populate tax_query terms parameter with post term

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

I need to populate the terms parameter in my tax_query with the current term of the post.

I have been trying to use the WP function wp_get_post_terms in a variable and then referencing that variable in the terms parameter to input the current posts term name.

I have been using the codex page as a reference, but I cannot seem to get it to populate.

Can anyone point me in the right direction??

```
//Returns Array of Term Names for "topic"
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'topic', array("fields" => "names"));
    echo $term_list;

    $args = array (
        'post_type'      => 'knowledge-base',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num', 
        'meta_key'       => 'top_four_num',
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'topic',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term_list,                                       

            ),
        ),                  
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            echo '<h2>' . the_title() . '</h2>';

        }
    } 

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here.

- As your code stand, `$post` is undefined. It is actually better to make use of `get_the_ID()` to get the post ID instead of `$post`
- `wp_get_post_terms()` makes an extra db call, so if you are really set on performance, I would rather use `get_the_terms()`
- You are returning term names, but then set the `field` parameter in your `tax_query` to `slug`. The field value should match the value of the term passed. Just a note, never ever use the `name` field in a `tax_query`, there is an issue with name sanitation in the `WP_Tax_Query` class. If you are using `wp_get_post_terms()`, set the `fields` parameter to `ids` to return an array of term ids

## EXAMPLES

### `wp_get_post_terms()`

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms(
    get_the_ID(), 
    'topic', 
    array(
        'fields' => 'ids'
    )
);

if (    $term_list
     && !is_wp_error( $term_list )
) {
    $args = array (
        'post_type'      => 'knowledge-base',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num', 
        'meta_key'       => 'top_four_num',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'topic',
                'terms'    => $term_list,                                       
            ),
        ),                  
    );
    // Run your custom query here
}
```

### `get_the_terms()`

```
$terms = get_the_terms(
    get_the_ID(), 
    'topic'
);

if (    $terms
     && !is_wp_error( $terms )
) {
    $term_list = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );

    $args = array (
        'post_type'      => 'knowledge-base',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num', 
        'meta_key'       => 'top_four_num',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'topic',
                'terms'    => $term_list,                                       
            ),
        ),                  
    );
    // Run your custom query here
}
```

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense!!! Thanks for the detailed explaination.. My code is now working as expected!! :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked ;-)